# How to setup Eclipse for C++ debugging

Tags: eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

For some reason I cannot manage to set up eclipse to debug C++ on ubuntu (13.10)

1. I installed CDT with both "CDT Main Features" and "GNU Toolchain" build and debug support
2. I installed gcc (`sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc g++ gfortran libgcc1 python-dev`)
3. I set up "Elf Parser" as under "C/C++ settings" in my CDT project.
4. I can "make", I can "build". I go to my cpp file (which has a .o file, created by the build), right click "run as: C/C++ application".

all I get is:
`No symbol table is loaded`

Also, all my includes, such as `#include <stdio.h>` show as a warning of "Unresolved Inclusion". what should I do?
Mind you, I tried several solutions on StackOverflow, but non seemed applicable to me.

I have no problem reinstalling from scratch if anyone here knows the correct sequence for Ububntu 13.10?